# How to use normal Entity functions on new ExternalIdentifier objects (e.g. Wikidata)?

Tags: entity, webservices

Is there any way to use the built-in `EntityXXX` on `ExternalIdentifier` objects? For me, it's more intuitive and easier to use `EntityProperties` on an entity like this:

```
EntityProperties[ExternalIdentifier["WikidataID", "Q180736", <|"Label" -> "Les Misérables", "Description" -> "1862 Victor Hugo novel"|>]]
```

[image]

Than useing this syntax:

```
WikidataData[ExternalIdentifier["WikidataID", "Q180736", <|"Label" -> "Les Misérables", "Description" -> "1862 Victor Hugo novel"|>], "NonIdentifierProperties"]
```

[image]

Comment: There's no built-in way of doing this. Part of that is just not wanting people to accidentally conflate the two - they often disagree for example. Another problem is that you can use an Entity in WikidataData, because many Entities can be used as if they were WikidataID ExternalIDs. So if you just used the string based Entity["type", "name"]["property"] syntax for both Entities and Wikidata, it'd be pretty confusing I guess to know what you mean unless, maybe,  "property" isn't a string for wikidata queries.